# how >> operator on streams returns a reference to itself

Tags: c++, reference, return

Say I've a class

```
class A{
A& operator+ (size_t ofst)
{
     //some calculation
     //return
}
};
```

here i cannot write

```
return this;
```

becuse A* cannot be converted to A&. So how to achieve this this? I want to return a reference not a pointer.

---

As an analogy there is >> or << operator for a stream class. As i know these two returns a reference to itself. How standard library achieves this?

Comment: Note: You generally don't return a reference from `operator +` (or `-`, `/`, etc..). You return a *value* constructed from the input parameter and your object, with the value being the result of the operation. In this case it is likely used for something besides "addition", so it may be different, just an fyi. If that param is what I think it is, `operator +=()` may be more appropriate regardless.

Comment: if i apply +/- operator on a iterator it may not return a value

Comment: Yes it will (or at least it better) even if that "value" is the equivalent `end()`

Comment: then how can we write cin>>x>>y, if cin>>x is not a cin object itself.

Comment: For *that* you return a reference to `*this`. See Lightness' answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Write `*this`.**

The unary `*` operator performs dereferencing. So, you start with the pointer `this`, and apply `*` to get the thing that it points to, i.e. the actual underlying object.

The result of `*this` is not actually a reference, but an *lvalue* which then happily binds to the reference which is the return value of your function/operator.

---

As for how streams do it, most operator overloads for streams are non-members:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyType& obj)
{
   os << obj.someStringRepresentationIGuess();
   return os;
}
```

Those that aren't will return `*this`:

```
std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(int x)
{
    doSomethingToAddIntToBuffer(x);
    return *this;
}
```

---

This does not usually apply to operators such as `+`, though it would to `+=`:

```
class A
{
   A operator+(size_t ofst)
   {
      A tmp = *this;
      tmp += ofst;
      return tmp;
   }

   A& operator+=(size_t ofst)
   {
      // some calculation
      return *this;
   }
};
```

This is because the convention is for `+` to apply to a *new* object; otherwise, the result of the following code would be entirely surprising:

```
int x = 5;
int y = x + 2;

// is y 5 or 7?
// is x 5 or 7?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return *this;
```

*Voila.*

You have to dereference your pointerif you want to assign it to a reference.

Answer (score 1):

You simply return *this. It will not be null unless the member function itself was invoked on a null pointer.